# Find the Addition and Multiplication tables for GF(7)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Find the Addition and Multiplication tables for GF(7).

I know in order to do this, I have to express it in terms of $Z_7[x]/(x+1)$, or some other irreducible polynomial of order 1. But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any help would be great, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, $GF(7) = {\Bbb Z}_7$. No need to consider polynomials. Just work modulo $7$.

Comment: Oh, its that simple? Ok, thanks!